# Unable to launch firebase emulators ui

Tags: java, firebase, macos, apple-m1, firebase-tools

Hello everybody: i can't launch my emulators , firebase init ok , ports ok , the problem seems to come from the ui . Anybody could help me ?

```
(base) jean-charlesdubien@airdejencharles firebase-demo-project % firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, storage
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  hosting[flutter-ultimate-ae8a4]: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting[flutter-ultimate-ae8a4]: Local server: http://127.0.0.1:5002/
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
⚠  ui: Fatal error occurred: 
   Emulator UI has exited with code: 1, 
   stopping all running emulators
i  ui: Stopping Emulator UI
⚠  ui: Error stopping Emulator UI
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  hosting: Stopping Hosting Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  auth: Stopping Authentication Emulator
i  storage: Stopping Storage Emulator
i  eventarc: Stopping Eventarc Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
i  logging: Stopping Logging Emulator
```

Node @19 then downgraded unsuccesfully. java jre19 mac M1 , tried on rosetta and M1 terminal

Thank you

downgrade node from 19 to 16
retry init and download emulators
try from terminal M1 and rosetta .

EDIT : mode -- debug

Node.js v18.15.0
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"/Users/jean-charlesdubien/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.4/server/server.js:569\n        re"use strict";\n          ^^^^^^^^^^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected string\n    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)\n    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)\n    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)\n    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)\n    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)\n    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47\n\nNode.js v18.15.0\n"}}
⚠  ui: Fatal error occurred:
Emulator UI has exited with code: 1,
stopping all running emulators {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Fatal error occurred: \n   Emulator UI has exited with code: 1, \n   stopping all running emulators"}}

Comment: thanks . it won't change anything , already downgraded to node@18

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me to downgrade to Node.js `v18.15.0`. I've had `v18.16.0` installed before.
https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.15.0/

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading the version helped me, as Chris.

Also, for everything to work, you need to delete the cache, in my case, it is the path "/Users/dmitroserdun/.cache/firebase"

Answer (score 0):

Node 19 is experimental and not officially supported (by Node or Firebase):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5608

Please downgrade to 18 and reply if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker for that its more a clean way, Im use this image
https://hub.docker.com/r/spine3/firebase-emulator

Answer (score 0):

Answers above, note the combination of:

- Downgrade to Node.js v18.15.0
- Delete cache (on Windows /Users/user/.cache/firebase)